# How to ensure no one can call an api Two times

Tags: c#

I have created an api in c# with following parameters

https://localhost/api/grantresource?resourceId=1&token=XXXXXXXXXX&crcCheck=YYYYYY

now there is a problem if someone calls this api/url twice resource is given twice. Need a solution that how i can avoid duplicate call.

1st parameter is resource which i want to give
2nd parameter is authentication token
3rd parameter is crcKey which ensures that data is not tempered across transmission.

Comment: What about invalidating the token after the first request ?

Comment: Wherever you have maintained `token` in your application keep another flag along with it. After first hit make it `false`

Comment: Add the token to a dictionary of type <string,bool> upon issue, setting the bool value to true.  In GrantResource check the dictionary for a true value - the first time the token is used, do a lookup and set the bool value to false.  Every additional time do the same but return an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a purpose?

1. Рrevent a client loads a server by constantly sending requests.
2. Give the customer a response only once according to url.

Solutions

Purpose 1. The easiest way is to deny send request on client before get response for previous request.

If it is needed to resolve this problem on server side you should create dictionary `<string (token), bool(flag)>`. When server side takes request then you set flag into false. When server sends response then set flag into true. If server takes request and flag is false, then server rejects request (sends response with error or some else indication about the need to get an answer to the previous one).

This dictionary you may save in `MemoryCache`.

Purpose 2. I had this case when it was needed to generate link only for one download of some file. Then I created collection with tokens. And when I created link to download I added token to the collection. When I took request then I removed token from collection. And if someone sent me request again (with same token) then I could not find it in collection and send response with error.

If lifetime of link (in my case) is enough short then you can save collections with tokens in `MemoryCache`. If lifetime of link is enough long (more than 24 hours) then I recommend to save this collection in database.